# How do I tell what type of CPU cache is in my laptop?

Tags: memory, cache, architecture

Is there an application for Ubuntu that could tell me details about CPU, CPU cache memory, memory hierarchy, cache architecture implemented in my system, cpu cache size, cpu cache, access cycle and cpu latency?

It could be GUI or CLI. I prefer an application within Ubuntu Repos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

open your terminal and type this

```
cat  /proc/cpuinfo
```

Example output:

```
 processor  : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 6
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2400.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 6
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est cid cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5983.63
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 15
model       : 6
model name  : Intel(R) Pentium(R) D CPU 3.00GHz
stepping    : 5
cpu MHz     : 2400.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fdiv_bug    : no
hlt_bug     : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 6
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx lm constant_tsc pebs bts pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est cid cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm
bogomips    : 5983.48
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Answer (score 3):

lstopo is a useful tool to show the CPU cache and logical CPU layout, to install use:

```
sudo apt-get install hwloc
```

and then:

```
lstopo
```

[image: lstopo output]

alternatively without a graphical output, use:

```
lstopo -
```

and you get something such as:

```
Machine (5695MB)
  Socket L#0 + L3 L#0 (3072KB)
    L2 L#0 (256KB) + L1 L#0 (32KB) + Core L#0
      PU L#0 (P#0)
      PU L#1 (P#1)
    L2 L#1 (256KB) + L1 L#1 (32KB) + Core L#1
      PU L#2 (P#2)
      PU L#3 (P#3)
  HostBridge L#0
    PCI 8086:0166
      GPU L#0 "card0"
      GPU L#1 "controlD64"
    PCI 8086:1502
      Net L#2 "eth1"
    PCIBridge
      PCI 10ec:8176
        Net L#3 "wlan1"
    PCI 8086:1e03
```

Answer (score 2):

ican did command line. I'll take the GUI one:

```
sudo apt-get install sysinfo
```

[image]

after installation

[image]
[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Hi Rinzwind , Brother i have added one more image to improve it , hope you don't mind . :D